# "From today (on / onwards) Or "As of today" Or "Starting today"

Tags: phrase-choice

I am wondering which choice sounds more natural and idiomatic in my sentence below and why?

> - I have decided to change my lifestyle.............

1. from today
2. from today on
3. from today onward(s)
4. as of today
5. stating today

To me, they all mean exactly the same thing in this particular context,

Comment: You missed out *from today **onward*** (without the final '**s**'), which has become [the more common form in American English today.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=from+today+onwards%2Cfrom+today+onward&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfrom%20today%20onwards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfrom%20today%20onward%3B%2Cc0) But this is essentially a matter of opinion - syntactically / idiomatically they're all perfectly acceptable.

Comment: I would probably say "from now on".

Comment: I'll go with 5 (assuming typo is fixed): starting today. I'd also be as likely to say "... starting right now" which has a bit more immediacy to it. None of those above are wrong though.

Comment: I'd go with "starting today" as well. There's an entire [Elvis Presley song](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/elvispresley/startingtoday.html) to exemplify that usage.